# URL Scheme not opening Junos Pulse on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I'm trying to open Junos Pulse app from my app by calling this on an iPhone 5c and it doesn't open.

```
NSString *stringURL = @"junospulse://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I got the URL Scheme from here:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

It opens on an iPhone 4s and iPad but not iPhone 5c.

Comment: What is your iOS system version on these devices?

Answer (score 0):

I need to add this to the plist file for iOS 9.  Where `appurlscheme` is the URL scheme for the app called in `openURL`.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
   <string>appurlscheme</string>
</array>
```